# Function with extensible record parameter passed as a parameter cannot be used from within a case statement

Tags: elm

I'm trying to extract some information from some records using extensible records. If I create a function taking the extensible record type and returning a string and use that within a case statement then there are no issues (`namedToString`, in the below example). However, if I attempt to use a function passed as a parameter (`stringFromNamed`) I will get an error complaining:

```
This business value is a: 
   Business  
But stringFromNamed needs the 1st argument to be:  
   Named a -> String (edited)
```

from the example code below:

```
type alias Named a =
    { a | name : String }

type alias Person =
    Named { address : String }

type alias Business =
    Named { employeeCount : Int }

type Change
    = PersonUpdate Person
    | BusinessUpdate Business

namedToString : Named a -> String
namedToString changeFields =
    changeFields.name

changeToString : (Named a -> String) -> Change -> String
changeToString stringFromNamed change =
    case change of
        PersonUpdate person ->
            -- This works
            namedToString person

        BusinessUpdate business ->
            -- This will cause the error
            stringFromNamed business
```

This example includes just the required code but a more complete example can be found at https://ellie-app.com/77nCPLh55j3a1

What is causing the issue and how can I achieve my goal of passing in a function which will extract some information from an extensible record?

Comment: Where is the function `stringFromNamed` defined? Or what do you pass as the function param to `changeToString`?

Comment: Check the expanded example at the link above but it could even be passing `namedToString` which works when used directly but not when passed as a parameter.

Comment: Oh, I missed the calling part at first. The types are not explicitly set, so Elm might be confused. Or the types are not what you expect. I've had some similar issues previously, but can't remember the solutions exactly. One thing you could try is to define a function type that you use everywhere. So instead of `(Named a -> String)` your function uses `SomeFunctionType`, where this is an alias as `type alias SomeFunctionType = (Named a -> String)`

Comment: `stringFromNamed` is a parameter, in the expanded example it is defined on line 64 in the call to `changeToString`.    
I have tried to create a type alias for the function type as you suggest but it doesn't appear to fix the issue unfortunately.

Comment: I have gotten around this issue by creating a record containing the fields in `Named`, `type alias NamedItem = {name : String}`, and constructing a new instance of this record (explicitly using a constructor, doesn't appear to work without use of the constructor) and making my function which previously took a `Named a` now take the `NamedItem`. It works but it's a bit messy and doesn't seem in the spirit of the language. I'd still like to know if I'm doing something wrong or if there's a better way to handle this.

Answer (score 4):

I discovered this issue in the Elm compiler repo: https://github.com/elm/compiler/issues/1959

This appears to be a bug in the compiler which can be worked around if you just want to pass an external record of one type to a function parameter. You can do this by removing the type signature of the higher order function, `changeToString` in the example above.

Unfortunately, if we wanted to perform the same action from the function parameter, e.g. `stringFromNamed`, on every case the error will return so another workaround must be found.

The workaround I'm using is to create a new record type which includes exactly the fields from the extensible record and then creating an instance of this from the fields of the other records adhering to the extensible record type. Not a big problem with only a couple of cases and an extensible record with only one field but this doesn't scale especially well. Example below:

```
type alias Named a =
    { a | name : String }


type alias OnlyNamed =
    Named {}


type alias Person =
    Named { address : String }


type alias Business =
    Named { employeeCount : Int }


type Change
    = PersonUpdate Person
    | BusinessUpdate Business


type Msg
    = UpdateCurrentChange Change


namedToString : Named a -> String
namedToString changeFields =
    changeFields.name


changeToString : (OnlyNamed -> String) -> Change -> String
changeToString stringFromNamed change =
    case change of
        PersonUpdate { name } ->
            stringFromNamed  { name = name }

        BusinessUpdate { name } ->
            stringFromNamed  { name = name }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that the function you're passing in takes `Named a`, and Elm doesn't know what the `a` refers to, so it ends up deciding it's a type mismatch.  If you change the type annotation to `(Named Business -> String) -> Change -> String` it will compile and work.

Comment: If I change the line `stringFromNamed business` to `namedToString business`, which is a function with the same signature, it will succeed, so I don't know that this is the issue, or if it is then I think the compiler should be able to work out what we want.